# Quebrar string em array limitando a quantidade de vezes em que a quebra é feita

Tags: javascript, array

Sei que temos o `split` pra quebrar a string em array, mas se eu quiser efetuar o `split` apenas a primeira vez que encontrar uma determinada característica?

Exemplo:

```js
const vogais = "a-e-i-o-u"

const arrayVogal = vogais.split('-')

console.log(arrayVogal)
```

```
[ 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' ]
```

Ao invés disso, ficasse assim:

```
[ 'a', 'e-i-o-u' ]
```

Answer (score 5):

Uma solução possível é você pode usar *regex* para encontrar um padrão desejado e realizar um `split` somente nesse primeiro caso de padrão encontrado.

No seu caso, quando o primeiro `-` for encontrado, realizar o `split` nele, usando a regex `-(.*)`, que serve para fazer o *match* do primeiro `-`.

Como ficaria seu código:

```js
const vogais = "a-e-i-o-u"

const arrayVogal = vogais.split(/-(.*)/, 2)

console.log(arrayVogal)
```

<sub>Repare no 2 dentro de split. Ele server para limitar apenas 2 items, pois o terceiro é uma string vazia. [Veja aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)</sub>

Agora vou criar uma função chamada `splitAtTheFirstMatch` que server para realizar o `split` no local desejado (`element`) de uma determinada string (`text`) e me retornar uma estrutura semelhante a que você informou (`[ 'a', 'e-i-o-u' ]`) de uma forma dinâmica;

```js
const vogais = 'a-e-i-o-u';

function splitAtTheFirstMatch(text, element) {
  const regex = new RegExp(element + '(.*)');
  
  return text.split(regex, 2);

}

// veja uns testes aqui
console.log(splitAtTheFirstMatch(vogais, '-'));
console.log(splitAtTheFirstMatch(vogais, 'e'));
console.log(splitAtTheFirstMatch(vogais, 'e-'));
console.log(splitAtTheFirstMatch(vogais, 'i-'));
console.log(splitAtTheFirstMatch(vogais, 'o-'));
```

O `new RegExp` server para passar dinâmicamente uma string para dentro da regex.

E agora você pode testar para qualquer elemento da string que você quiser realizar o `split`.

---

#### OBS:

- Não tenho certeza se esta é a melhor *regex* para o caso, mas funciona pra resolver seu problema.

#### OBS2:

- Com a ajuda do @hkotsubo, um detalhe importante sobre a minha *regex* e acho interessante acrescentar na resposta:

> E `.*` funciona porque o ponto corresponde a qualquer caractere, e o quantificador `*` é "ganancioso" e tenta pegar a maior quantidade possível de caracteres, e por isso ele vai até o final da string. Por isso que tudo que vem depois do hífen é colocado no array (sem os parênteses não funcionaria).

Comment: Só pra deixar a explicação mais completa, a [documentação de `split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split#Description) diz que quando a regex tem um grupo de captura (os parênteses), o conteúdo deste grupo também é colocado no array. E `.*` funciona porque o ponto corresponde a qualquer caractere, e o quantificador `*` é "ganancioso" e tenta pegar a maior quantidade possível de caracteres, e por isso ele vai até o final da string. Por isso que tudo que vem depois do hífen é colocado no array (sem os parênteses não funcionaria)

Comment: Exatamente. Boa acrescentada! Eu esperava que voce fosse comentar minha resposta, pois ela envolve regex e eu não domino *regex* muito bem, mas tenho um trecho de código que implementa `...(.*)` e só foi descobrir que precisava do parêntese debois de quebrar a cabeça. Eu optei por usá-la (*regex* dentro do `split`) pra deixar a resposta com minimo de código possível, mas que atenda a pergunta.

Answer (score 5):

Uma solução é fazer o `split` e depois juntar as partes de acordo com o que você quer:

```js
const vogais = "a-e-i-o-u";
const arr = vogais.split('-');
const arrayVogal = [arr[0], arr.slice(1).join('-')];
console.log(arrayVogal); // [ 'a', 'e-i-o-u' ]
```

Ou seja, eu pego o resultado do `split` e crio outro array contendo 2 elementos:

- o primeiro elemento resultante do `split`
- a junção dos demais elementos: primeiro usando [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) para pegar do segundo elemento em diante, e depois [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) para uni-los em uma única string

---

Mas você também pode generalizar para N partes, usando `slice` para pegar os N primeiros elementos (em vez de pegar somente o primeiro):

```js
// separa o texto usando o separador, e faz a separação no máximo "limite" vezes
function splitLimit(texto, separador, limite) {
    var partes = texto.split(separador);
    // pega os primeiros elementos (até o limite)
    var result = partes.slice(0, limite);
    // pega os demais (após o limite) e junta tudo em uma única string
    result.push(partes.slice(limite).join(separador));
    return result;
}

const vogais = "a-e-i-o-u";

// separa no máximo 1 vez (resultando em 2 partes)
console.log(splitLimit(vogais, '-', 1)); // [ 'a', 'e-i-o-u' ]
// separa no máximo 3 vezes (resultando em 4 partes)
console.log(splitLimit(vogais, '-', 3)); // [ 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o-u' ]
```

---

Para este caso específico, outra alternativa é usar [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) para obter o índice em que ocorre o primeiro hífen, e depois pegar as partes da string antes e depois desta posição:

```js
const vogais = "a-e-i-o-u";
// posição do primeiro hífen
let i = vogais.indexOf('-');
// criar array com 2 elementos
let arrayVogal = [
    vogais.slice(0, i), // do início da string até o hífen
    vogais.slice(i + 1) // tudo depois do hífen
];
console.log(arrayVogal); // [ 'a', 'e-i-o-u' ]
```

Se quiser, pode [fazer este teste](https://jsbench.me/3skiag2nbu/1) e ver qual é a alternativa mais rápida.

---

Obs: Também coloquei ponto-e-vírgula no final das linhas. Pode parecer "frescura", e sei que o JavaScript "aceita" o código sem ponto e vírgula e "funciona", mas isso evita algumas situações bizarras que podem ocorrer se você não usá-los, como [essa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1169596) e [essa](/q/432960/112052) (veja mais sobre isso [aqui](/q/3341/112052)).